# My navbar doesn't stick to the top of the webpage if its position is set to fixed

Tags: html, css

I'm programming a website right now and I want it to have a navigation bar that sticks to the top if you're scrolling. I know this is possible with:

```
h1 {
    Position: fixed;
}
```

But that just isn't working for me. I made a `JSFiddle`, you look at it here: https://jsfiddle.net/qayzbjo0/3/

Hope you can help me with my problem. If you find the solution, would you please fix it in the `JSFiddle` and send the new URL to me? :)

Thanks in advance!

```css
.navbar {
 background-color: #60C8FF;
 margin: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #36B9FF;
}

.navbar h1 {
 padding: 5px;
 border-bottom: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
 display: inline;
 width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  
  <div class="navbar">

   <h1 class="navbar">NeurOp - Specialist in neurale oplossingen</h1>

   <ul>
    | <li>Home</li> | 
    <li>Neuraal Netwerk</li> | 
    <li>Toepassingen</li> | 
    <li>Over ons</li> | 
   </ul>

  </div>

   <div class="home">

    <p>AAP<br>AAP<br>AAP<br>AAP<br>AAP<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br>HOI<br></p>

   </div>

<!-- Algemene voorwaarden in PDF bestand downloaden in footer -->

 </body>
```

Comment: If you want the nav bar to stick to the top while the user is scrolling you need to apply the position: fixed to your nav element

Comment: Well, if I do this same thing with just the H1 tag and the p tag in another document, it does work....

Comment: syntax error, missing semicolon after width `.navbar ul {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%
  position: fixed;
}`

Comment: code should be in your question. It could help someone else who might have the same issue, and if your code is here it won't disappear. 3rd party sites can disappear, or the content (in this case a fiddle) can be deleted.

Comment: did you want the blue background to apply to the links as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be work:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #60C8FF;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  position:fixed;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #36B9FF;
  padding-top:0;
}
.home{
  padding-top:50px
}

.navbar h1 {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
  position: fixed;
}
```

Here is JsFiddle : [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/tw7evr3c/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `position: fixed;` to your nav element.

See the jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/qayzbjo0/1/

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #60C8FF;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #36B9FF;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I will advise you to name your classes differently on the different elements since you don't want to apply the same style to all of them. Second, you must set the `position:fixed` to the global div. Here is the [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/qayzbjo0/2/) I propose.

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #60C8FF;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #36B9FF;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar h1 {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
  position: relative;
  top:50px;
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;

}

.navbar ul {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my [FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Illdapt/098n7es0/)

This solves all your issues of using a fixed header and fixing the `navigation` items so they appear when using `position:fixed;`

You will notice that I took the `navbar` class off of the `<h1>`, if that class is applied to both, the nav items would be hidden. Use a separate class to style the `<h1>`

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: #60C8FF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #36B9FF;
    position: fixed;
    top: -5px;
}

.navbar h1 {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar ul {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100% position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <h1>NeurOp - Specialist in neurale oplossingen</h1>
        <ul>
            | <li>Home</li> |
            <li>Neuraal Netwerk</li> |
            <li>Toepassingen</li> |
            <li>Over ons</li> |
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="home">
        <p>AAP
            <br>AAP
            <br>AAP
            <br>AAP
            <br>AAP
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>HOI
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Algemene voorwaarden in PDF bestand downloaden in footer -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

give your ul element the following class

```
<ul class="navbar-fixed-top-sticky">
            | <li>Home</li> | 
            <li>Neuraal Netwerk</li> | 
            <li>Toepassingen</li> | 
            <li>Over ons</li> | 
        </ul>
```

and also remove `position:fixed;` from the following

```
.navbar ul {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;}
```

hope it will work for you.